# tomcat 5.5 + apache Configure a group app inside tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, httpd, ajp

My apache redirects to my tomcat

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
...
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
...
</VirtualHost>
```

But my tomcat has more webapps, and I would have another apache http virtualhost pointing to this tomcat.

I need this behavior:

```
www.example.com/tomcatapp1  --> tomcat http://localhost:8080/myexamples/tomcatapp1
www.example.com/tomcatapp2  --> tomcat http://localhost:8080/myexamples/tomcatapp2

www.foo.com --> tomcat http://localhost:8080/foo
```

myexamples can be a folder? How I configure tomcat to do that?
What I need to use?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why do you need the myexamples folder? Couldn't you just deploy tomcatapp1 and tomcatapp2? These would be folders.

I think this could be what you are looking for:

```
 <VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
 ...
   ProxyPass /tomcatapp1 http://localhost:8080/tomcatapp1
   ProxyPassReverse /tomcatapp1 http://localhost:8080/tomcatapp1

   ProxyPass /tomcatapp2 http://localhost:8080/tomcatapp2
   ProxyPassReverse /tomcatapp2 http://localhost:8080/tomcatapp2
 ...
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost www.foo.com:80>
 ...
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/foo
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/foo
 ...
 </VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps.